# Python: Loop through multiple text files, extract target strings, and append them to list

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text-extraction

(Python 3.6.3)

I need to extract IP addresses and the dates from multiple text files that contain a long text string. After this, I want to append these data to the Python lists. These text files also reside in sub-directories so I used 'os.path.join(subdir, file) to make sure the script captures these as well.

Here's my code:

```
ip_address = []
dates = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            text_data = open(os.path.join(subdir, file))
            ip_address.append(re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', text_data))
            dates.append(re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\/[0-9]+){2}', text_data))
        else:
            pass
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-de806e6c6270> in <module>()
      6         if file.endswith('.txt'):
      7             text_data = open(os.path.join(subdir, file))
----> 8             ip_address.append(re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', text_data))
      9             dates.append(re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\/[0-9]+){2}', text_data))
     10         else:

C:\Users\591159\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    220 
    221     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 222     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    223 
    224 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I assume the data I am trying to extract is not in a string form but don't fully understand what it means. I appreciate any pointer to the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean to `read()` the data in - e.g. `text_data.read()` Currently, `text_data` is an iterator of strings, not a string.

Comment: Yes, I meant to read the data in as a string. What method should I use to replace my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a suggestion from @AChampion, I modified my code to the following and it works as intended:

```
ip_address = []
dates = []

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            with open(os.path.join(subdir, file), 'r', encoding='utf8') as text_file:
                text_data = text_file.read().replace('\n', '')
            ip_address.append(re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', text_data))
            dates.append(re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\/[0-9]+){2}', text_data))
        else:
            pass
```